# Java JDBC with PostgreSQL: PreparedStatement Execute with Add Column Query returns false

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc, ddl

I am trying to add a column to a database table and

```
PreparedStatement  ps = con.prepareStatement(query);  
ps.execute();
ps.close();
```

query is something like (valid SQL)

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN mycolumn datatypeinfo
```

Anyway, it executes fine and the column is created. But the execute statement returns false. I tried with executeUpdate and that returns 0 rows.

Note that this whole thing is within a transaction with con.setAutoCommit set to false. So I am not sure if that is the problem. The issue is that I have to create the column before I can go ahead with other update queries. So it has to run in a transaction.

Comment: Why not use the executeUpdate() method when you don't expect a ResultSet?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't return anything. As it says, it returns 0 for SQL statements that return nothing, such as DDL statement. I guess I will just rely on whether an exception has been thrown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return value of `execute()` does not indicate whether it was successful, but if the query that was run returned a result.

As the `ALTER TABLE` does not return a result, the `execute()` rightfully returns `false`

Quote from the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute%28%29):

> *Returns:* true *if the first result is a ResultSet object;* false *if the first result is an update count or there is no result*

Comment: Fair enough, but how do I check if the column has been added? Do I need to use DatabaseMetaData to go back to the table and check if it is in effect? (In essence, can I do it in one step instead of two?)

Comment: If it fails, it will throw an exception.